# Multiple file upload urls with edgee:slingshot

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
var images = [];
let uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("articles"); 

// file input
let files = document.getElementById("someId").files; 

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
    uploader.send(files[i], function (error, downloadUrl) { 
        if (!error) { 
            //save all download urls in an array 
            images[i] = downloadUrl; 
        } 
    }); 
}
console.log(images);
```

When I access the images array above after filling it with download urls, it is being empty. Any variable value is lost after the send() block. I would like to store all the download urls in an array, so how do I do this?

Comment: Missing closing `)` at `uploader.send()` , closing `}` at  `for` loop? Does `uploader.send()` return results asynchronously?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to type it. It sends the file asynchronously and works on one file at each instantiation. As in the code above, I would like to store an array of urls, but this doesn't let me do.

Comment: `console.log(images)` could be called before asynchronous callback completes. You could check if `i` is equal to `files.length` before calling `console.log(images)`; e.g., within callback, `if (i === files.length) {console.log(images)}`

Comment: The reason that console.log() is outside the loop is that I would like to save the whole 'images' array content into a database, after the loop finishes. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Slingshot's `uploader.send()` is an asynchronous process.

Therefore it looks to me that it is just a [classic async task misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

I.e. `console.log(images)` **is** called before `uploader.send` callbacks are executed.

Furthermore, you will experience scope issue by using your `i` variable within the callback function. When it executes, `i` will have a different value. Typically it will already be equal to `files.length`. Which means all your callbacks will write on the same array item `images[files.length]`.